# Simple form with pixel manipulation in Qt

Tags: forms, qt, pixel, qpainter, qimage

I'm completely newbie to Qt
i want to create a 800X600 window that just show some circle and be able to manipulate pixels of the form. there is no interaction between user and form(no click, no dblclick,...) it just shows some circles with one color and lines with different pixel colors(each line may have different pixel colors)
also i want to be able to change the coordination system, i mean change it from top-left to the center of the window. could anyone help me do that with some sample code?
thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Please look at the many examples and tutorials in the Qt docs. If you're stuck on a specific problem, feel free to post here with the code you have produced and the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [downloading the Qt Creator (IDE)](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools), then reading through the [tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tutorials.html).  There's a whole host of very useful information provided for free, including a lot of the code samples you are looking for.

The following examples might also be of particular interest:

1. [Animation Framework Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-animation.html)
2. [Graphics View Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-graphicsview.html)
3. [Painting Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-painting.html)